# Python Возможно ли импортировать файлы с функциями в любой части кода?

Tags: python

Интересует возможность импорта файла с функциями в любой части кода, например в зависимости от какого-то условия. Если пытаюсь стандартным способом сделать например "from shop import*" выдает ошибку что импорт произведен не в модульном уровне программы. (работает только когда в самом вверху производится импорт)

Comment: Не бывает такой ошибки, импорты работают в абсолютно любых местах в коде. Вы что-то не договариваете

Comment: Я надеюсь, `from import shop * ` (а не `from shop import *`)это просто опечатка? Вообще, PEPы рекомендуют не пользоваться таким способом импорта из-за возможных проблем с пространствами имен.

Comment: Да опечатка. А что лучше использовать чтоб не было проблем с пространством имен?

Comment: Какие у вас проблемы с пространством имён?

Comment: Пока никаких, просто спрашиваю на будущее. А насчет ошибки которая у меня вылазит - SyntaxError: import * only allowed at module level

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы собираетесь импортировать модули или их части через import * внутри какой-либо подпрограммы, то получите ошибку, поскольку питон этого сделать не позволяет во избежание проблем с пространством имен (nested scopes) на основании рекомендаций [PEP227](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/). Однако, вы можете импортировать отдельные методы из модуля - то есть `from foo import bar` будет работать и внутри функции, что, тем не менее, все-таки является нарушением рекомендаций [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите сделать импорт всего пакета то пишите просто `import shop`.

Если вам требуется только его часть то `from shop import name`, а если `name` можно сократить для последующего использования то ещё написать `from shop import name as n`.

Делать импорт можно в любой части кода.